# QSettings does not write in registry after Windows 10 October update

Tags: c++, qt, windows-10, registry, qsettings

I build an application that downloads and installs various types of software. When installing the software I write some values on the registry. Everything was working fine until recently with the Windows 10 October update. It seems that now my application does not write to registry. Does anyone have a clue or a solution to my problem?

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\MyCompany\\MyAppName\\"+softType, QSettings::NativeFormat);
settings.beginGroup(software->getID());
settings.setValue("id", software->getID());
settings.setValue("title", software->getName());
settings.setValue("version", software->getVersion());
settings.setValue("installationPath", software->getInstallationPath());
settings.setValue("executable", software->getExecutable());
settings.endGroup();
settings.sync();
```

Comment: What does the `settings.sync()` call return? You might not have an access to write to that registry location.

Comment: settings.sync() it's a void function that writes any unsaved changes to permanent storage, and reloads any settings that have been changed in the meantime by another application. It was working fine. Now with the Windows 10 October update it does not. :/ @vahancho

Comment: Ah, right. Sorry, I meant `QSettings::status()` function call after you synced the changes.

Comment: I get QSettings::AccessError, which means that I cannot write since it's read only. What I don't understand is that everything was working fine. I didn't change anything on my user, I am admin so I should have access to write and I didn't change anything on my code.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly run your application as Administrator?

Comment: I ran QtCreator with admin rights and it works fine. Now I feel like a total noob for not trying this, BUT my user is Admin and I also wrote the following code on the .pro file so my app is executed with admin rights. CONFIG += embed_manifest_exe
QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS += $$quote( /MANIFESTUAC:\"level=\'requireAdministrator\' uiAccess=\'false\'\" ). @ManuelH Thanks a lot for your time guys. I really appreciate it!